# does revit import xdata contains in a dwg file? if not, why?

Tags: c#, cad, revit, dwg

I need to collect xdata information pf .dwg file in revit. but I did not find a way to do that. I'm wondering whether this kind of information is also imported  as other information? I think revit should import this kind of information. because I noticed that when revit export to dwg file, it did include some xdata information in the file.

I googled with "xdata revit", "xdata" ... but nothing satisfied my need.
I searched revit forumn and found nothing either.
I search revit document, nothing found.
I really don't know what else I can do...

Comment: Why dont you ask on the revit forum, you are likely to get help faster than here

Comment: @TheGeneral I would when I could. thank you for your suggestion.